# I've tried to make a program that converts time in string format to integer format through a list

Tags: java

```
public static int[] convert(String time)
{
    int time_len = time.length();
    System.out.printf("There are %d characters in this sentence\n" ,time_len);

    int[] t = new int[time_len];

    for(int CHAR = 0; CHAR < time_len; CHAR++) {
        char character = time.charAt(CHAR);
        if (character != 'h'){
            System.out.println(character);
            t[CHAR] = character;
        }
        else System.out.println("");
    }

    for(int num = 0; num < t.length; num++){
        System.out.println(t[num]);
    }
    return t;
}
```

//When I try to use this code for some reason all the values in the array t are increased by 48

Comment: "all the values in the array t are increased by 48" do you mean, you don't know why, say `'0'` becomes 48?

Comment: Yes that just happens for some reason and I have no Idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [ASCII Table](https://www.ascii-code.com/).
What you are trying to get is the decimal value of the symbol, where a symbol is actually a number. In that case `0` has `48` decimal value, so that's why all your numbers are increased. You are saving the decimal value of the character, not the value itself.

Comment: Oh I see! I'm treating Java as though it were python when converting from a non int to an int value. (I'm a beginner in programming in java, yet I'm applying some concepts of python into it.)

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are possible :

either change type of **t** from int to char:

```
public static char[] convert(String time)
{
    int time_len = time.length();
    System.out.printf("There are %d characters in this sentence\n" ,time_len);

    char[] t = new char[time_len];
    ...
}
```

or try to get the character value by subtracting the integer value of '0' from each number:

```
t[CHAR] = character - '0';
```